# How to lookup a data dictionary in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have small app in that I manage sales territories. One territory can have x addresses. This is working just fine. I can display a list of territories and go into territories' details and display the addresses.

My question: In the territories table I have a field called sales_rep_id. How do I say the territories index view to display the 'sales_rep_name' instead of the 'sales_rep_id'? The 'sales_rep_name' is stored in the sales_rep table.

Do I have to do another has_many belongs_to relation?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
t = Territory.first # just an example
name = t.sales_rep_name
```

In your territory model something like this:

```
def sales_rep_name
    if sales_rep
        sales_rep.name
    else
        ""
    end
end
```

You can read up on has_many vs belongs_to here, the belongs_to should go in the model with the foreign key, in this case the Territory model.

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: In the territories model I wrote
    territory
        belongs_to :sales_rep
in the sales_rep model I worte 
    sales_rep
        has_many :territories

Then in the view I'm saying
<% @territories.each do |territory| %>
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
  <td><h3><%= link_to territory.name, territory %></h3></td>
  <td><%= territory.handed_out %></td>
  <td><%= territory.sales_rep.name %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
And I'm getting the error
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you sure that every territory has a sales rep assigned? If sales_reps are optional then you should make "sales_rep_name" a method in the territory model, and have it check whether there is a sales_rep assigned.

Comment: You're right. I had a few territories that were unassigned. How would a method like this look like? def sales_rep_name(sales_rep_id) name = sales_rep.name Sorry, just improvising I really don't know... Another question that I have in this context: how do I remove the sales_rep_id from territories when I delete a sales_rep?

Comment: See my edited answer for the first. I believe the second will happen automatically since you told rails the belongs_to relationship